# Powershell - RPC, OBJ Null and -Replace ERRORS in MySQL insert query

Tags: mysql, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise

I have this insert query that's not inserting properly and is really annoying. I will explain briefly what I tried and what I actually want to achieve.

What my PS script does:

1. ping every computer from a database table
2. if ping succeeds, get username logged on from the computer
3. insert to database table the following values : username, hostname, online(true/false)

Now here are the problems that keep showing up.

**Problem 1: If I use the following command:**

$username =  Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $workstation -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Username;

It will insert the username values like so: **SUPER/user1** which is Okay but I want to get rid of the "SUPER/" and just keep the actual username "user1" before inserting.

I tried using the one below but it doesnt work:

```
 $username =  Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $workstation -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty -replace '^.*\\'  Username;
```

The command in **problem 1** will give me these TWO errors:

**Cannot process argument because the value of argument "obj" is null. Change the 
value of argument "obj" to a non-null value.**

And

**Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable.**

How can I ignore those two errors?

I hope someone can help me out because its really annoying. thanks in advance everyone.

**Powershell script:**

```
foreach($pcname in $workstation_list){

        $command = $connection.CreateCommand();
        $command.Connection  = $connection;
        $command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO workstation_userlogged
                                 (username,hostname,online)
                                 VALUES (@username,@hostname,@status)";

        ### ============================================================= 
        ### values to be assigned as a parameters
        ### =============================================================           
        $workstation = $pcname;                
        $test_ping   = Test-Connection -ComputerName $workstation -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
        $status      = [bool](Test-Connection $workstation -Quiet -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue);

        #if status is TRUE get username
       if($test_ping)
        {
            $username = Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $workstation -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Username;
            echo $username;
           #echo -replace '^.*\\' $username;         

           #if ping succeeds but no user is logged
           if($username -eq "") 
           {
                $username = "no user logged";  
           } 

        } #end if

        #if ping DOES NOT succeed set username value to NULL and status to FALSE
        elseif(!$test_ping)
        {
            $username = [DBNull]::Value;
        }

       ### ============================================================= 
       ### Assign parameters with appropriate values
       ### ============================================================= 
        $command.Parameters.Add("@username", $username)     |   Out-Null
        $command.Parameters.Add("@hostname", $workstation)  | Out-Null
        $command.Parameters.Add("@status",   $status)       | Out-null
       ### ============================================================= 
       ### Execute command query
       ### ============================================================= 
        try{
            $command.ExecuteNonQuery() | out-null;
            Write-Host "Successfully inserted in Database";
        }
        catch{
            Write-Host "Caught the exception";
            Write-Host "$_";
        }

       ### ============================================================= 
       ### clear parameter values
       ### =============================================================  
         $command.Dispose()
         $workstation = "";
         $username    = "";
         $status      = "";
         $test_ping   = "";
     }#end for each loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding problem 1 try this:

```
$username = (Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $workstation -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName
$username = $username.split("\")
$username = $username[1]
```

Problem 2 is because of a Problem on the remote machine. For some debuggin help look at Microsofts documentation: [Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4494.windows-server-troubleshooting-the-rpc-server-is-unavailable.aspx).

Allthough this article is tailored to MS Server most of it should be applicable on client machines too.

Comment: hey it did INSERT into my table perfectly. However there are 2 errors showing for both "split" and the "array". For "split" **You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression**  and for the "array" **Cannot index into a null array.**  can you please explain? thanks!

Comment: hmm i guess this happens if the Get-WmiObject does not return an object (probably because of your second problem). At this point $username is $null so split and and the following will fail

Comment: so how can I ignore the errors so the script may still run without displaying it. Thanks

Comment: put it in a try catch to keep it running, the error will still be displayed though